# How to convert path into a shape in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, shapes

I am trying to covert some paths into shapes.
Let's say I have something like this:

[image: initial path]

and I need to convert it into something like this:

[image]

How am I supposed to go about this?

I am using Inkscape 0.92.

Comment: Actually, a circle is called a 'shape' in Inkscape (like a rectangle or a star), and the thing you get when you convert its stroke to a path is a path. I was a little bit confused by the terminology here :)

Answer (score 4):

To convert a stroked path into a filled shape made of paths, select the stroked circle, and then click *Path > Stroke to path*

Here's an example

[image]